# Trying to simplify the code

Tags: c#-4.0

Does anybody suggest me how can I simplify the follow code

```
            private bool isMethodCalled;
            private void CallMethod()
            {
                if (!isMethodCalled)
                {
                    this.CallCertainMethod();
                    isMethodCalled = true;
                }
            }

            private int field1;
            public int Property1
            {
                get
                {
                    CallMethod();
                    return this.field1;
                }
                set { this.field1 = value; }
            }

           private int field2;
            public int Property2
            {
                get
                {
                    CallMethod();
                    return this.field2;
                }
                set { this.field2 = value; }
            }


            private int field3;
            public int Property3
            {
                get
                {
                    CallMethod();
                    return this.field3;
                }
                set { this.field3 = value; }
            }
```

Comment: Simple is relative. Where do you see the complication?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AOP framework like PostSharp to create an attribute which would call `CallMethod` and just use automatic properties for `Property1`, `Property2` and `Property3`. Although it wouldn't save much in the number of lines of code unless there are a lot of other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can simplify is the following:

```
private void CallMethod()
{
    if (!isMethodCalled)
    {
        this.CallCertainMethod();
        isMethodCalled = true;
    }
}
```

to:

```
private void CallMethod()
{
    if (!isMethodCalled) this.CallCertainMethod();
    isMethodCalled = true;
}
```

As a side note:

I don't know what `CallCertainMethod()` does. Just in case, it is not recommended to query data and mutate state at the same time. See [Command Query-Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation), which states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both. In other words, asking a question should not change the answer.